# Implicit Broadcast android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED NOT working

Tags: android, bluetooth

My receiver is not getting called when I declare an implicit broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BluetoothConnectionReceiver_"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"

    android:permission="android.permission.BLUETOOTH,
    android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I understand that in Oreo, there is a restriction on some implicit broadcasts. But in the doc, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions, ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED are not among them.

Comment: I am running the code in Oreo

Comment: Have you declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />` successfully granted this permission?

Comment: @Sagar Yes - I have

Comment: Did you found any solution @slingkid?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
 in your AndroidManifest and you must check in runtime to verify if the permission is granted for the versions >= Lollipop.

Use this code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else {
        //Permission is already granted
    }
```

Using `ContextCompat` and `ActivityCompat` classes you don't check if the running SDK/OS version is >= Lollipop. In case of the version < Lollipop the method `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` will return true.